# Does indices()->refresh() wait for completion?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I'm developing a PHP website using Elasticsearch ([Official PHP client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/index.html)).

I'm writing tests that need to be sure the newly inserted documents
are ready to search before proceed.

To do this, after indexing new documents, I call:

```
$client->indices()->refresh()
```

My question is: Does $client->indices()->refresh() wait for refresh completion before making the PHP script go on? Or does not wait for its completion?

In the second hypothesis, how can make it wait for completion before making PHP test go on?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not exactly what was asked about `refresh()` but this is what I do to ensure a document is available to search as soon as it's indexed. I use the [`?refresh`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/docs-refresh.html) parameter in the index operation:

```
$data = [ 
  'type' => 'mytype',
  'index' => 'myindex',
  'id' => 'thisid',
  'refresh' => 'wait_for',
  'body' => [ /* document */ ]
];

$client->index($data);
```

Comment: Thank you. I was aware of "wait_for" but in some tests, I prefer to not change app behavior with "wait_for" but use a refresh call to simulate that the refresh time is passed and documents are become available in search.